# Reserializing row index after row selection in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'gene':["foo","bar","qux","woz"], 'cell1':[5,0,1,0], 'cell2':[12,90,13,0]})
df = df[["gene","cell1","cell2"]]
```

That looks like this:

```
  gene  cell1  cell2
0  foo      5     12
1  bar      0     90
2  qux      1     13
3  woz      0      0
```

After performing row selection I get this:

```
In [168]: ndf = df[(df[['cell1','cell2']] == 0 ).any(axis=1)]

In [169]: ndf
Out[169]:
  gene  cell1  cell2
1  bar      0     90
3  woz      0      0
```

Note that now `ndf` has row index `1` and `3` how can I re index it to `0` and `1`.

The expcted output is:

```
   gene  cell1  cell2
0  bar      0     90
1  woz      0      0
```

I tried this but failed:

```
ndf.reset_index
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
ndf.reset_index(drop = True)
```